# Retrieve coredata attribute and set UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, uilabel

I'm having problems retrieving an attribute called "totalWorkTimeInHoursString" and setting it as text in a UILabel. Right now I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func calculateTotalWorkTimeInHoursStringSum() {

    //CoreData
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    var results: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!


        if (results.count > 0) {
            for res in results {
                var totalWorkTimeInHoursString = results.valueForKey("totalWorkTimeInHoursString") as String
                totalWorkTimeInHoursStringSumLabel.text = "\(totalWorkTimeInHoursString)"
            }
        }else {
            println("zero results returned, potential error")
            }
    }

}
```

This is the tableView cell that the label is in.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here. When I run the app it shows nothing in the UILabel aside from the default text. I know that "totalWorkTimeInHoursString" is saving to core data properly because it is being stored and retrieved in a tableview elsewhere in my project.

Comment: results is an array, but you're trying to access it as a dictionary...

Comment: One sec. I see your specific error.

Answer (score 0):

During the following loop, you're accessing the individual elements, i.e. `res`s, of the results array, but within the loop, you're using `results` when you should be using `res`  and thus you end up trying to manipulate `results` like it's a dictionary and not an array. So, in short, replace `results.valueForKey` with `res.valueForKey`:

```
for res in results {
    var totalWorkTimeInHoursString = res.valueForKey("totalWorkTimeInHoursString") as String
    totalWorkTimeInHoursStringSumLabel.text = "\(totalWorkTimeInHoursString)"
}
```

Comment: huh. tried that, it's still not showing in the label when I run.

Comment: @Leighton Hm... Are you sure your label outlet is hooked up properly? If the default text is still showing, either (1) the IBOutlet isn't hooked up or (2) there are no "results" and this for loop isn't executing. Because if the label were hooked up and the for loop were executing, even if `totalWorkTimeInHoursString` was nil or anything other than the default string, the label text wouldn't still be set to its default.

Comment: yea, I just checked. Even disconnected, deleted, and remade an outlet with a whole new label. Still not working. Could it have something to do with the fact that the label is contained in a tableview cell? Would it be possible to just enter totalWorkTimeInHoursString in cell.textlabel.text? I'm not sure how to reference a specific static cell that way. I'll post an image of the situation. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Leighton Oh, I see. Are you using the tableview delegate methods?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. I just created a tableViewController and made static cells with labels/text fields in them.

Comment: Sorry, you might be able to tell I'm new to swift and programming.

Comment: @Leighton Never mind my auto layout theory. Setting the label in viewDidLoad worked for me. Are you sure your results array isn't empty? If you put an NSLog or breakpoint in the for loop does it execute?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what was going on, but I figured it had something to do with the label being in the tableView so I put the label in a regular UIView and it worked fine. I'm just going to leave it that way because I think I like the design for the app better this way anyway. Still curious how the table view caused the problem though.

Comment: @Leighton No problem, but just one more question since I'm curious myself... Was it just a UITableView or was it a UITableViewController? I'm asking because only UITableViewControllers are technically allowed to have static cells.

Comment: yes, its a UITableViewController. I'm currently using it with static labels, and segues from the cells to various UIViewControllers. Thats how I'm making a "menu" in one of my tabs from my tab based app.

Comment: @Leighton Oh, ok. Then I have no idea at all. Congrats on getting it to work. :)